# Why does Image.IO.read() return null in this case?

Tags: java

**ImageLoader.java:**

```
public class ImageLoader {
    private static BufferedImage image;

    public ImageLoader() {
    }

    public BufferedImage loadImage(String filePath) throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath));
        return image;
    }

    public static BufferedImage loadImage(Class classPath, String filePath) throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read(classPath.getResourceAsStream(filePath));
        return image;
    }
}
```

**Library.java:**

```
public class Library {
    public static final String ResourcePath = "./res/";
    public static final String ImagePath = ResourcePath + "Images/";
}
```

**Using ImageLoader.java in three ways:**

1. `BufferedImage test = new ImageLoader().loadImage(Library.ImagePath + "imageFile.png");`
2. `BufferedImage test = new ImageLoader().loadImage(Main.class, Library.ImagePath + "imageFile.png");`
3. `BufferedImage test = new ImageLoader().loadImage("/Images/" + "imageFile.png");`

Why is it that only the 3rd case works and the first and second case doesn't? I believe it has something to do with the `Library.ImagePath` static variable.

If there is a way to fix it, please describe below!

Comment: Which ```Library``` class are you using / what value does ```Library.ImagePath``` have in your case?

Comment: @DavidTanzer oh right, let me add that to the question!

Comment: Are you sure you need `./` at the start of `ResourcePath` instead of just `/`?

Comment: @ferrybig interesting proposal, but that doesn't change the fact that Image.IO.read() returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it has to do with your image path. When you expand the variable, the value is

```
./res/Images
```

but from your third example, it looks like the image is in the classpath at

```
/Images/imageFile.png
```

So try changing the ImagePath to:

```
public static final String ImagePath = "/Images/";
```

The difference here is (Note: *I am only guessing from now on*), that, in your class path, the images seem to be deployed in the Images folder. On the file system, you seem to have a "res" folder in the root folder where you start your application.

Say your folder structure looks like that:

```
myProject
+--- res
|    +---Images
|    \---Texts
\--- src
```

When you start the application in `myProject`, and `res` is on your classpath then the path to images will be different when you load via classpath or via File:

```
new File("./res/Images/..."); //Relative to the working directory of the app!
classPath.getResourceAsStream("/Images/..."); //Root is your classpath, i.e. "res"!
```

Comment: Because you have a CLASSPATH entry called /Images and none called /res/Images, of course.